# Comparing one street address with a column of street addresses to find a match

Tags: vba

I have two data sources with street address names, cities, and zips that I'm trying to find which addresses have the highest match percentages and return the maximum value. I have a VBA code that matches two cells strings "Address Compare" but need to compare one address to an entire column.

Please view the VBA code examples attached. One image contains the "Address Compare" used to match two cells while the other code uses a For Loop to index a column and call "Address Compare" module to compare the indexed column with the specific cell.

I cannot figure how to save the matching percentages in an array and return the maximum value. Can I get any help?

[image: Excel Image]

```
Function AddressCompare(first_string As String, Second_string As String, _
                               Comparing_Letters As Integer) As Double
  Dim int_character As Integer, Comparing_LettersMatch As Integer
  Dim n_Gram_List1 As String, n_Gram_List2 As String, n_letter_Gram As Variant
  Dim n_Gram_array1 As Variant

  For int_character = 1 To Len(first_string) - (Comparing_Letters - 1)
      If n_Gram_List1 <> "" Then n_Gram_List1 = n_Gram_List1 & ","
      n_Gram_List1 = n_Gram_List1 & Mid(first_string, int_character, Comparing_Letters)
  Next int_character

  For int_character = 1 To Len(Second_string) - (Comparing_Letters - 1)
      If n_Gram_List2 <> "" Then n_Gram_List2 = n_Gram_List2 & ","
      n_Gram_List2 = n_Gram_List2 & Mid(Second_string, int_character, Comparing_Letters)
  Next int_character

  n_Gram_array1 = Split(n_Gram_List1, ",")

  For Each n_letter_Gram In n_Gram_array1
      If InStr(1, n_Gram_List2, n_letter_Gram) Then
        Comparing_LettersMatch = Comparing_LettersMatch + 1
      End If
  Next n_letter_Gram

  AddressCompare = Comparing_LettersMatch / (UBound(n_Gram_array1) + 1)
End Function




Function MatchAddyCompare(first_string As String, Arr1rng As Range) As Double
  Dim Arr1() As String: Arr1 = Arr1rng.Value
  Dim i As Integer
  Dim ArrayLen As Integer
  Dim MACC() As Variant
  ArrayLen = UBound(Arr1) - LBound(Arr1) + 1
  For i = 1 To ArrayLen
      Call AddressCompare(first_string, Arr1(i), 2)
      'MACC(i) = AddressCompare
  Next i
  'MatchAddyCompare = AddressCompare
 
End Function
```

I've added a second message so everyone can see that if I directly compare two cells with "AddressCompare" function, I get a 81% match which is great. However, I need a code that can run the one cell versus the entire column and return the highest percent match. [image: Here is the second image]

Comment: This [link](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/fuzzy-matching-new-version-plus-explanation.195635/) may help.  It's an old post, but should still work.

Comment: Thanks! However, "FuzzyMatch" coding does not work to help me match addresses. I think "FuzzyMatch" works better with peoples first and last names instead of physical addresses. Thanks again though for the reference!